# How do I style RootElement

Tags: monotouch.dialog

I need a way to style Monotouch Dialogs RootElement. I need to change the background and font color.

I'm have created a custom RootElement as below

```
public class ActivityRootElement : RootElement
{
    public ActivityRootElement (string caption) : base (caption)
    {

    }

    public ActivityRootElement(string caption, Func<RootElement, UIViewController> createOnSelected) : base (caption, createOnSelected)
    {
    }

    public ActivityRootElement(string caption, int section, int element) : base (caption, section, element)
    {
    }

    public ActivityRootElement(string caption, Group group) : base (caption, group)
    {
    }



    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        tv.BackgroundColor = Settings.RootBackgroundColour;
        return base.GetCell (tv);
    }

    protected override void PrepareDialogViewController(UIViewController dvc)
    {
        dvc.View.BackgroundColor =  Settings.RootBackgroundColour;
        base.PrepareDialogViewController(dvc);
    }

}
```

I am then calling the custom root element as below passing in a custom DialogController

```
    section.Add (new ActivityRootElement(activity.Name, (RootElement e) => {
                return new ActivityHistoryDialogViewController (e,true);
            }));
```

The root Element style is not been applied. Any help would be apprciated!!

Comment: This question is getting old, but did you get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color to be the only thing you see in the TableViewController, you need to set the BackgrounView to null. There is a view overtop to apply the styling, which will hide the color you are looking for.

Try this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
    tv.BackgroundColor = Settings.RootBackgroundColour;
    tv.BackgroundView = null;
    return base.GetCell (tv);
}

protected override void PrepareDialogViewController(UIViewController dvc)
{
    dvc.TableView.BackgroundColor =  Settings.RootBackgroundColour;
    dvc.TableView.BackgroundView = null;
    base.PrepareDialogViewController(dvc);
}
```

Comment: **I am now using a xamarin theme and actually getting the cell works.** `public override MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tv)
  {
   tv.AllowsSelection = false;
   var cell = base.GetCell(tv);
   cell.SelectionStyle = MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
   FitpulseTheme.Apply (cell);
   return base.GetCell (tv);


  }`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work, I had to override the `MakeViewController` method and cast the UIViewController that it normally returns to a UITableViewController, then make my edits.

```
protected override UIViewController MakeViewController()
{
    var vc = (UITableViewController) base.MakeViewController();

    vc.TableView.BackgroundView = null;
    vc.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red; //or whatever color you like
    return vc;
}
```